# Laravel best practices listening to JSON data from external API

Tags: laravel, cron, phpwebsocket

I have this use case of building an automation tool, that needs to get data from an external API and notify a specific user.

I'm thinking about using a cron job to fetch the API every 2 minutes and triggering an event to notify the user.
Is there any alternative approach, something to listen to an API?

Comment: Is it only while the user is logged in?

Comment: Yes, the data is relevant for just the logged-in user.

Comment: Ok cool. Look at the Task Scheduling in Laravel then

Comment: Thanks, for your comment I'm aware of Task Scheduling, don't know if there is another approach.

Comment: Ok well is the data specific to that user and are you inserting it into the database? What exactly is it? If you can say

Comment: So my user is inserting a Pinterest user, and I'm getting JSON data of the latest pins, and yes I'm inserting the data to the database, I'm thinking about a user-generated job to get the Pinterest data for each user in my database. hope I explained the use case.

Comment: Ah ok. I personally would use task scheduling, but not sure if there’s anything else that’s more suited.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I guess another way would be to do it from the front end as well using Ajax requests to your server and then your server reaching out to the external api,storing the results in the database and then sending back to front end where you do your thing with it.

Comment: Yeah, but that requires a user to be on the site, I think the Task Scheduling, is the best thing to go for.

Comment: The ability to "listen" to the API depends on the particular API. Some API's provide webhook callbacks, which will hit your endpoint every time their is an event.